# What is the meaning of the math symbol $\because$?

Tags: notation

This is essentially a $\therefore$ symbol upside down, and I have seen it in some proofs, not many. What does it mean?

Comment: Hint: If I can't find out a symbol I try to draw it here: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html most of the time it's recognized (your symbol was a bit hard though, but it recognized it on the second try)

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid That site looks really cool, but I still can't get it to do anything more than three dots in horizontal line for the symbol in question :) Although, trying to draw the "therefore" sign I wound up with the "because" sign by accident lol

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid [This site](http://shapecatcher.com/) worked better for me. It's not for LaTeX, but it does Unicode, which is helpful in most cases. Once you find what the character is called, you can probably figure out how to use it or look it up on Google.

Comment: @BrianJ: I found that it initially gave me five symbols of the form "three dots in a horizontal line", *but* it offered a "Show more" link, and the next five symbols included the desired one. (That said, I'm not sure that finding out how to write a symbol in LaTeX is, in general, sufficient for finding out what it means.)

Comment: @mbomb007 thanks, that tool looks also very useful!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The inverted form of the [therefore sign ( $\therefore$ )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therefore_sign) used in proofs before *logical consequences*, is known as the [because sign ( $\because$ )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therefore_sign#Related_signs)  and it is used in proofs before *reasoning*.

Answer (score 27):

This symbol just means 'because'. If it was facing up, it means 'therefore'.

Kinda feel like this is too short but I guess there's not much to this question.

Comment: I read the answer as "It's just because. Period." Couldn't help laughing... +1

Comment: I suggest putting "because" and *therefore* in quotes or italics to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: It's sometimes read as "since".

Comment: Maybe you could offer some speculation as to why one seems to be used more than the other.

Answer (score 0):

$\therefore $ You will have seen it next to the conclusions ... it is equivalent to "therefore", "then", "consequently", "in conclusion", "we obtain" and a long etcetera.

Its inverse is 
$\because $ that it means << because >>.